# The existence of invertible pseudodifferential operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If $M$ is a closed manifold, then can we find a first order pseudodifferential operator $\Lambda$ acting on ${\cal D}'(M)$ (the distribution on $M$) such that there is a pseudodifferential operator $\Lambda^{-1}$ of order $-1$ such that $\Lambda\Lambda^{-1}=\Lambda^{-1}\Lambda=I$ (the identity operator)?

My first thought is to set $\Lambda=(I-\Delta)^{1/2}$ where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator on $M$. But I am not sure how to make this well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you're looking for is the theory of pseudodifferential operators on manifolds. Peter Gilkey's book has a good introduction.